# Guardar variable de una función en C

Tags: c, random

Tengo esta función:

```
int NumeroDado(){
    float t=0.0;
    int dado=0;
    t=rand()/32768.0;
    dado=1+(int)(6*t);
    printf("\nDado: %d",dado); //Sirve para comprobar el numero.
    return(dado);
}
```

La cosa es que el resultado de esa función tengo que guardarla en el main, he probado con hacer directamente:

```
numero=NumeroDado();
```

Pero no funciona, no se como puede guardarla sin tener que modificar la función NumeroDato()

Inicia el programa y directamente debería cargar en la variable `numero` un numero aleatorio que saldría de NumeroDado()

El programa se inicia y intenta que en numero se guarde el numero aleatorio de NumeroDado(), si mostramos por pantalla los valores de la variable numero muestra números del tipo 490789, es decir, valor que no deberían aparecer, creo que el problema está a la hora de guardar el resultado de NumeroDado() en la variable numero.

En el main tengo: srand(13579);

Gracias!!

Comment: Cuando dices "*Pero no funciona*" ¿A qué te refieres?

Comment: A primera vista parece estar bien. Deberías incluir un [mcve] para poder reproducir tu problema. Un saludo.

Comment: En la variable numero no se guarda el return de NumeroDado()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu error es muy sutil, y se debe a que has supuesto que la función `rand` genera números entre 0 y 32767. Pero no es así.

Como se puede observar en la línea en la que generas un aleatorio, haces una división, para que el número generado sea un número real entre 0 y 1.

```
t = rand() / 32768.0;
```

El problema es que la función `rand`  genera números aleatorios entre 0 y `RAND_MAX`, que como mínimo es 32767, lo que cabe en un entero con signo de 16 bits, es decir, es 2^15 - 1. Pero `RAND_MAX` puede ser mayor, y en muchos casos, lo será. Depende del sistema. En tu sistema, `RAND_MAX` es mucho mayor que 32767, quizá valga 2^31 - 1 o incluso más.

Al hacer la división te puede salir un número entre 0 y 1, pero también números reales mucho más grandes. Si quieres generar un número real entre 0 y 1, tienes que dividir de la manera siguiente.

```
t = rand() / RAND_MAX;
```

Pero ojo con los tipos, ya que `RAND_MAX` se expande a un tipo integral, con ancho dependiente de tu sistema, pero en definitiva, un número entero. Y además, `rand` devuelve un entero. Por tanto, deberías hacer un casting de alguno de los operandos para que el resultado sea un número real.

```
t = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
```

Además, luego multiplicas por 6 y sumas 1, con lo que intentas generar números entre 1 y 7. Si quieres números entre 1 y 6, necesitas multiplicar por 5 y sumarle 1.

```
dado = 1 + (int)(5 * t)
```

Sin embargo, la manera más fácil de generar valores enteros entre 1 y 6 es hacer el módulo 5 de `rand` (genera números entre 0 y 5) y sumarle 1.

```
dado = 1 + rand() % 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que quieres hacer algo como esto:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "cstdlib"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <ctime>

    using namespace std;


    int NumeroDado(){
        float t=0.0;
        int dado=0;

        srand(time(NULL));
        t= rand()%3276;
        dado=1+(int)(6*t);
        printf("\nDado: %d",dado); //Sirve para comprobar el numero.
        return(dado);
      }

    int main(void){
        int resultado=NumeroDado();
        cout<<"El valor retornado por la funcion es "<<resultado;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: esa es idea pero en resultado no se guarda el valor de NumeroDado(): ``` int resultado=NumeroDado();```

Comment: Bueno, y qué se guarda? Quieres decir que el printf que hay dentro de `NumeroDado()` muestra un valor, y en cambio el `cout << resultado` del programa principal muestra otro? A mi me salen exactamente los mismos valores (por ejemplo, 11977). Otra cosa es que el valor no sea lo que esperas, porque... ¿qué esperas?

Comment: La cosa es q se debe guardar en el main porque la función deberá volver a sacar otro numero para compararse, NumeroDado() saca un numero entre 1 y 6 pero al intentar meter ese valor en una variable del main es cuando me da valores raros

Comment: La pregunta está etiquetada como [tag:c], tu respuesta es [tag:c++].

Comment: También estoy trabajando en C como apunta @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación de tu respuesta, y del error que cometió el OP.